# How does getBalance() work?

Tags: transactions, web3js, accounts

How does the `eth.getBalance()` function work? Which file does it call exactly? How and where all parameters are passed? Please someone explain it to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can clone the repository and perform `git grep getBalance` and then `git grep GetBalance`.

You'll soon fall in the file https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c8695fae359aa327da9203a57ffaf4f2d47d4370/core/state/statedb.go#L245-L251

Then you'd do `git grep ") Balance"`, only to reach

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c8695fae359aa327da9203a57ffaf4f2d47d4370/core/state/state_object.go#L370-L372

Now, you really need to read the files.

```
// empty returns whether the account is considered empty.
func (s *StateObject) empty() bool {
    return s.data.Nonce == 0 && s.data.Balance.BitLen() == 0 && bytes.Equal(s.data.CodeHash, emptyCodeHash)
}

// Account is the Ethereum consensus representation of accounts.
// These objects are stored in the main account trie.
type Account struct {
    Nonce    uint64
    Balance  *big.Int
    Root     common.Hash // merkle root of the storage trie
    CodeHash []byte
}
```

From here, we can deduce that is just a variable in memory, so somebody must have to fill it sometime!

Well. I'll leave you the rest as exercise. You need to figure out who is instantiating an `Account`, when the state of this account is set, and where is the persistence (HINT: DB Functions).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different kind of answer.

When a dapp calls `web3.eth.getBalance()`, web3 prepares and sends a [JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getbalance) request to the provider. If you're connected over IPC (this is the usual if you're using `geth attach`), then it writes to a file called `geth.ipc`, which geth then reads. If it's over the standard RPC (i.e. from a browser), web3 sends a HTTP POST to the node (usually at `http://localhost:8545`).

The end result is then calculated however the node does it (different nodes do it differently) and then the answer is sent back. web3.js decodes it and returns with a normal javascript object (in this case, a BigNumber).

What is the form of this request and reply? It's basically plain JSON. There's no reason it has to be web3.js. You can use `curl` (over HTTP) for the same effect. For example

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":["0xe7466f6aa35b04ac950274833dc9c43ef8e05d33", "latest"],"id":1}' localhost:8545
# returns
# {"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"0x00000000000000056bc75e2d63100000"}
```

This was using [testrpc](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc), which stores all of its data in memory, not on the disk. So the answer is partially, "It depends."

Comment: you didn't tell about files which will be used?

Comment: Like I said, it depends on the client. testrpc does not store its chain in files at all, as far as I know.